# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column - NO TYPOS NOR WRONG ' ` "

Tags: mysql, sql, database, cakephp

I'm using cakePHP to create a todo-application. CakePHP creates queries for you etc. That's why there must be no typo.

The error:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Projecttask.projecttasks_name' in 'field list'
```

The query:

```
SQL Query: SELECT `Itemrequirement`.`itemreq_id`, `Projecttask`.`projecttasks_name` 
FROM `gtd`.`itemrequirements` AS `Itemrequirement` 
LEFT JOIN `gtd`.`projecttasks` AS `ProjecttaskParent` ON (`Itemrequirement`.`itemreqs_rel_projectparents` = `ProjecttaskParent`.`projecttasks_id`)    
LEFT JOIN `gtd`.`projecttasks` AS `ProjecttaskChild` ON (`Itemrequirement`.`itemreqs_rel_projectchilds` = `ProjecttaskChild`.`projecttasks_id`) 
WHERE 1 = 1 
ORDER BY `Itemrequirement`.`itemreq_id` asc LIMIT 10000
```

The database:
[image: part of database]

I'm growing quite clueless, as I've tried loads of things in phpmyadmin manually..

Comment: Should you not be selected `Projecttaskparent.projecttasks_name` as that is your given alias in the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `projecttasks` twice

```
LEFT JOIN `gtd`.`projecttasks` AS `ProjecttaskParent` ...
LEFT JOIN `gtd`.`projecttasks` AS `ProjecttaskChild`  ...
```

but with aliases `ProjecttaskParent` and  `ProjecttaskChild`, so you must use an alias instead of the table name

```
`ProjecttaskParent`.`projecttasks_name`
```

or

```
`ProjecttaskChild`.`projecttasks_name`
```

Your query should look as below (with `ProjecttaskChild` alias fro example)

```
SELECT `Itemrequirement`.`itemreq_id`, `ProjecttaskChild`.`projecttasks_name` 
FROM `gtd`.`itemrequirements` AS `Itemrequirement` 
LEFT JOIN `gtd`.`projecttasks` AS `ProjecttaskParent` ON (`Itemrequirement`.`itemreqs_rel_projectparents` = `ProjecttaskParent`.`projecttasks_id`)    
LEFT JOIN `gtd`.`projecttasks` AS `ProjecttaskChild` ON (`Itemrequirement`.`itemreqs_rel_projectchilds` = `ProjecttaskChild`.`projecttasks_id`) 
WHERE 1 = 1 
ORDER BY `Itemrequirement`.`itemreq_id` asc LIMIT 10000
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't knew you'd also had to use the alias when calling fields! Selecting as answer whenever ready :)

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting from database name ProjectTask and you use an alias (ProjectTaskParent and ProjectTaskChild)

Your query should be:

```
SELECT `Itemrequirement`.`itemreq_id`, `ProjecttaskParent`.`projecttasks_name` FROM `gtd`.`itemrequirements` AS `Itemrequirement` LEFT JOIN `gtd`.`projecttasks` AS `ProjecttaskParent` ON (`Itemrequirement`.`itemreqs_rel_projectparents` = `ProjecttaskParent`.`projecttasks_id`) LEFT JOIN `gtd`.`projecttasks` AS `ProjecttaskChild` ON (`Itemrequirement`.`itemreqs_rel_projectchilds` = `ProjecttaskChild`.`projecttasks_id`) WHERE 1 = 1 ORDER BY `Itemrequirement`.`itemreq_id` asc LIMIT 10000
```

Change `Projecttask`.`projecttasks_name` for `ProjecttaskParent`.`projecttasks_name` or `ProjecttaskChild`.`projecttasks_name`

Answer (score 0):

### There is no Projecttask

From the error message:

> Unknown column 'Projecttask.projecttasks_name' in 'field list'

So there is a table/alias `Projecttask` and a field `projecttasks_name`. Except in the query:

```
FROM `gtd`.`itemrequirements` AS `Itemrequirement` 
LEFT JOIN `gtd`.`projecttasks` AS `ProjecttaskParent` ...   
LEFT JOIN `gtd`.`projecttasks` AS `ProjecttaskChild` ...
```

The table `projecttasks` has two different aliases, i.e. the problem is not that the field doesn't exist in the table its that there is no *table* in the query with that name/alias.

Probably the query you want is:

```
SELECT 
    `Itemrequirement`.`itemreq_id`, 
    `ProjecttaskParent`.`projecttasks_name` # <- alias updated
FROM 
    `gtd`.`itemrequirements` AS `Itemrequirement` 
LEFT JOIN 
    `gtd`.`projecttasks` AS `ProjecttaskParent` ON (...)    
LEFT JOIN 
    `gtd`.`projecttasks` AS `ProjecttaskChild` ON (...) 
WHERE 
    1 = 1 
ORDER BY 
    `Itemrequirement`.`itemreq_id` asc 
LIMIT 10000
```

### PHP code?

The code for the query isn't shown but therefore you need to change

```
$Itemrequirement->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Projecttask.projecttask_name' ...
```

to

```
$Itemrequirement->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'ProjecttaskParent.projecttask_name' ...
```

Or alternatively use [escapeField](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/additional-methods-and-properties.html#model-escapefield-string-field-null-string-alias-null) to ensure the alias is correct

```
$Itemrequirement->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        $Itemrequirement->ProjecttaskParent->escapeField('projecttask_name') ...
```

Comment: I'm not using PHP. It was obviously just a SQL-bug, to show the cakephp code would be unneccesary.

Comment: "I'm using cakePHP to create a todo-application. CakePHP creates queries for you" - that's 100% confusing if infact you are not using PHP, plus the question is tagged with `cakephp` (which is how I found it). If the queries _did_ come from CakePHP, the error is in the php code, and.. how can you show the cakephp code if there isn't any because you're not using PHP? So much confusion in so little words =).

Comment: you're the one confusing cakephp with regular php.